# JSON gcm message from server not being recognised on the android client

Tags: android, android-intent, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send and receive a JSON GCM message but on the client it seems to always come through as UTF8.

```
protected HttpURLConnection post(String url, String contentType, String body)
throws IOException {
    Print.logInfo("In HttpURLConnection: " + contentType + body);
    byte[] bytes = body.getBytes();
    HttpURLConnection conn = getConnection(url);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setUseCaches(false);
    conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(bytes.length);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", contentType);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=" + key);
    OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
    out.write(bytes);
    out.close();
    return conn;
}
```

On the server the UTF8 message is:
In HttpURLConnection: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8registration_id=APA91...&delay_while_idle=0&collapse_key=Test&time_to_live=2419200&data.Data1=Value+1&data.Data2=Value+2&data.Data3=Value+3

and the JSON message is:
In HttpURLConnection: application/json{"delay_while_idle":false,"collapse_key":"Test","data":{"Data1":"Value 1","Data2":"Value 2","Data3":"Value 3"},"time_to_live":2419200,"registration_ids":["APA91..."]}

with multicast result
MulticastResult(multicast_id=5036...,total=1,success=1,failure=0,canonical_ids=0,results: [[ messageId=0:1362.. ]]:

Both messages are successfully received on the client but I can not get the json format to be recognised.

```
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
    String inAction = intent.getAction();
    // check to see if it is a message
    if (inAction.equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE")) {
        // if your key/value is a JSON string, extract and parse it using JSONObject
        String json_info = intent.getExtras().getString("data");
        if (json_info != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json_info);
                payload = jsonObj.get("Data1")  + "\n"
                        + jsonObj.get("Data2")+ "\n"
                        + jsonObj.get("Data3");
                }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                // do nothing
                return;
            }
        }
        else {
            payload = intent.getStringExtra("Data1")  + "\n"
                    + intent.getStringExtra("Data2")+ "\n"
                    + intent.getStringExtra("Data3");
            }
    }
}
```

In Both cases json_info is null. I am using a java servlet on the server running apache/tomcat.

Please Help. Many Thanks

Comment: Last time I had a problem like this was because I had some character into the string to json_encode and in this case the function puts in `null`, I don't know about GCM but maybe this is the case too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The JSON object is only used in the communication of your server with the GCM server. The app never gets a JSON object. The data of the notification is passed as key/value pairs. If for some reason you want to pass a JSON payload, you should encode it as a String and pass that String as the value of one of the key/value pairs inside the `data` JSON object. Then you'll have to read that value from the extras in the intent and parse the JSON.

> onMessage(Context context, Intent intent): Called when your server
>   sends a message to GCM, and GCM delivers it to the device. If the
>   message has a payload, its contents are available as extras in the
>   intent.

Actually this quote is more relevant :

> data
>
> A JSON object whose fields represents the key-value pairs of the
>   message's payload data. If present, the payload data it will be
>   included in the Intent as application data, with the key being the
>   extra's name. For instance, "data":{"score":"3x1"} would result in an
>   intent extra named score whose value is the string 3x1. There is no
>   limit on the number of key/value pairs, though there is a limit on the
>   total size of the message (4kb). The values could be any JSON object,
>   but we recommend using strings, since the values will be converted to
>   strings in the GCM server anyway. If you want to include objects or
>   other non-string data types (such as integers or booleans), you have
>   to do the conversion to string yourself. Also note that the key cannot
>   be a reserved word (from or any word starting with google.). To
>   complicate things slightly, there are some reserved words (such as
>   collapse_key) that are technically allowed in payload data. However,
>   if the request also contains the word, the value in the request will
>   overwrite the value in the payload data. Hence using words that are
>   defined as field names in this table is not recommended, even in cases
>   where they are technically allowed. Optional.

Comment: Eran, Thank you and very kind for taking the time to provide a detailed response. I was initially confused by documentation and some examples on stack overflow suggesting that JSON is passed directly to the app.